# GitLab and Jenkins connection Issue

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I have successfully installed Jenkins and GitLab, But here I am facing connection issue between to GitLab and Jenkins for CI.

Here I have completed steps are below.

1. Manage Jenkins >> Configure System.

   Under Gitlab Section GitLab connections are the success.
2. I created New Job and under Source Code Management. I see below issue.

   > Failed to connect to repository : Error performing command: git
   >   ls-remote -h http://10.78.150.58/root/tch-demo.git HEAD.

Any one can help here. thanks.

Comment: Did your problem solved? I am in same situation, successfully connected jenkins to gitlab but gitlab Jenkins CI not integrate and have error.

Comment: ## You might want to install ngrok <https://ngrok.com/docs> <http://10.78.150.58/root/tch-demo.git> this looks like a private Ip. You have to expose your port to the public for gitlab to access Jenkins.

Answer (score 2):

You need to activate the service in GitLab at least.
Follow these guides:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/integration/jenkins.html

https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin#using-it-with-a-job

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did as per your suggestions, But still I see same issue. Connection is success in between the serves. :(

Comment: Did you try different repositories links formats? I mean:
ssh://...
https://....
git://... \n In my case the only regular URL worked fine

Comment: I successfully connected jenkins to gitlab but gitlab Jenkins CI not integrate and have error